# Android adding action buttons problems

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I tried to add two action buttons on the action bar, for visibility one is defined as:

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
```

another one is defined as:

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

The problem is I can see the `ic_action_search` icon but I could not see the `ic_action_overflow` icon. This is the `main_activity_actions.xml` in `menu` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  xmlns:MyFirstApp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
<!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      MyFirstApp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
      android:title="@string/action_settings"
      MyFirstApp:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

and this is the `Java` code that includes the buttons:

```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    //return true;
   }

   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle presses on the action bar items
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_search:
    //  openSearch();
        return true;
    case R.id.action_settings:
    //  openSettings();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

So whats wrong with my code?

cheers

Comment: As far as I can see, your code is working just as you set it up to work - the first icon with the value `ifRoom` is showing, unlike the other icon which has the value `never`, hence it's not appearing on the screen.

Comment: I like to see the other buttons hide in the `overflow` icon, so how do I achieve that? I am following the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

Comment: Are you testing it on (emulated) device that has *hard* menu/settings key? Quote from developer.android.com "The overflow icon only appears on phones that have no menu hardware keys. Phones with menu keys display the action overflow when the user presses the key." Also, the overflow icon should be there by default, so I guess this was the problem

Comment: Yes, I was testing the app on the emulators - Nexus S, generic QVGA 2.7 devices, but Nexus S does not have hardware keys and suppose to be working?

Answer (score 0):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"  />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

it is work